# Internet Llive streaming to LAN

Tags: streaming, video-streaming

I am watching a football match on live stream from a given website..

Is it possible for me to stream the same video via LAN to my friends? Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be done, at lease not that I'm aware off, why can't he just go to the same website as you? Wouldn't that be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to re-stream the video directly from the net. But depending on the video stream provider, some of them allow you to embed the video in an iframe or using a different method.

If the video stream provides an html embeddable code you can't re-transmit the video from your machine but if you have a service such as LAMP/WAMP, you can host a webpage over the LAN that your friends will be able to reach with ease. They will be forced anyway to have an active internet connection in order to watch it.

If we are talking about a live stream from [www.livestream.com](http://www.livestream.com) you'll find the sharing resources in the lower right corner. If you click it you will find the "**embed**" options, choose it and you'll be directed to the customization area where you can define things like colors, size, and a few other options as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

In the third step you'll get the code, which looks like:

```
<iframe width="560" height="340" src="http://cdn.livestream.com/embed/wfmz_traffic?layout=4&amp;height=340&amp;width=560&amp;autoplay=false" style="border:0;outline:0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><div style="font-size: 11px;padding-top:10px;text-align:center;width:560px">Watch <a href="http://www.livestream.com/?utm_source=lsplayer&amp;utm_medium=embed&amp;utm_campaign=footerlinks" title="live streaming video">live streaming video</a> from <a href="http://www.livestream.com/wfmz_traffic?utm_source=lsplayer&amp;utm_medium=embed&amp;utm_campaign=footerlinks" title="Watch wfmz_traffic at livestream.com">wfmz_traffic</a> at livestream.com</div>
```

After grabbing the code, simply create a new html document, let's call it "`footballmatch.html`" but you can call it whatever you wish. Insert the next code inside of it, note that the next code already includes the iframe mentioned previously.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe width="560" height="340" src="http://cdn.livestream.com/embed/wfmz_traffic?layout=4&amp;height=340&amp;width=560&amp;autoplay=false" style="border:0;outline:0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><div style="font-size: 11px;padding-top:10px;text-align:center;width:560px">Watch <a href="http://www.livestream.com/?utm_source=lsplayer&amp;utm_medium=embed&amp;utm_campaign=footerlinks" title="live streaming video">live streaming video</a> from <a href="http://www.livestream.com/wfmz_traffic?utm_source=lsplayer&amp;utm_medium=embed&amp;utm_campaign=footerlinks" title="Watch wfmz_traffic at livestream.com">wfmz_traffic</a> at livestream.com</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will produce a frame in the upper left corner, with the video player in a web page that you can place in the root of your web server and reach it via `http://localhost/footballmatch.html`

If you succeed then simply make sure you have por 80 (or 8080) open and share it via your IP as: `http://192.168.1.133/footballmatch.html` (change the ip number for whatever you currently have, fixed ip is strongly recommended).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the effort but if all my friends do not have a similar net connection as mine, so this wont help